# Double bracket missing in Oracle Linux

Tags: scripting, oracle-linux

So I was trying to write a script in an Oracle Linux server and nothing worked. To begin with, there is no double bracket as far as I can tell.

Also, the error messages I get are weird. For instance, this code :

```
[[ -f 'fake' ]] || { echo "There is a missing file"; } ;
```

Throws :

```
Bash : echo not found
```

I clearly understand the difference between the distribution and the shell you are interacting with, which makes the issue more weird.

I am a long life Centos/Ubuntu scripter so this experience has really been a bummer.

Can someone elaborate any other differences I Should be aware  in this new environment?

Comment: It works for me. Check what shell you are running.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm running Bash. And also the script has a shebang with it. I'll check the version in a while.

Comment: How do you know you are running bash?

Comment: @MichaelHampton because it's my default shell.and the error itself contains "bash"

Comment: Strange, that doesn't look like a real bash error message.

Comment: 1. what is shebang? 2. `command -v echo` ? 3. do you have some bizzare include for functions and do you change PATH?

Comment: echo is part of coreutils please check if someone deleted.